# How to fill a Combobox from foreach in a different class

Tags: c#, winforms, list, arraylist, combobox

I am trying to fill a comboBox and a secondary form from a separate class file and I think I have the basics wrong.

The following is shortened to show the bones of what I have and what I think I may be doing wrong. I am not sure if I should be using  List<> to populate the comboBox or an Array and suspect in either case my method declaraction is wrong and I cannot find a reference to the comboBox to populate from within the foreach loop.

OK the program.cs for my settings Form. This is not the main form but is the one I am looking to populate when a user select the comboBox.

Program.cs

```
class Settings
{
    public partial class Settings : Form
    {
        // a bunch of String declarations used throughout

        public Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }   
}
```

The method within a class in a separate file is

Functions.cs

```
class functions
//This is a separate class to the Settings Form but same namespace.
{
    //some global variables here

    public string getDomain(string webURL)
    {
        //more variable declarations
        //webURL is a value from the Settings Form
        //code to send query to website, get the response and filter the response.
        //This is the response filter

        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:domains/DAV:domain", nsmgr))
        {
            strNode = node.InnerText;
            responseString += strNode + " ";
            list.Add(strNode);
            //I would like to simply Add.Items(strNode) to the Settings.Form.cbxDomains but not as simple as this.  
        }
        //this returns all the correct information as a space separated string.
        return responseString;       
    }
}
```

From [Update UI from a different thread in a different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009681/update-ui-from-a-different-thread-in-a-different-class)

I thinks there are 2 things I should do.
1. change the form initialisation from InitilizeComponents() to

```
 settingsWindow = new MyForm();
   Application.Run(form);
```

2. Then simply call `Settings.settingsWindow.cbxDomain.Add>items(responseString);`
   But do I also need to change the actual method to something like
   `public void List<String> getDomain(string webURL)`

I am so confused. Most examples show it the other way of updating the class from the combo not the other way and some say create it as an array.

I actually think it could even be trimmed down further into one or 2 lines instead of the foreach, but that is way beyond my skillset at this time.

Comment: You are trying to fill combobox in one form from the some function in other class?

Comment: Yesm That is waht I am trying to do

Comment: you should use a message in a case like that or add them all to a list and send it also via message, its not the responsability of the parser to add it to a combobox

Comment: You have some custom generic class that you want to populate it or simply just with some string/int

Comment: At which place are you trying to set the values of your combobox? If you want to change the combobox somewhere outside your form class, then you need to pass a reference... Anyway I wouldn´t see the benefit...

Comment: I have a separate class so it is easier to use in other projects and perhaps a library later on. This function is useful for many other applications besides my simple form app.

Comment: Ok just one more thing. You are getting one or multiple values from XML file and with them you want to populate combobox?

Comment: I am receiving multiple items from the XML and separate them in the foreach loop. sometimes only 1 sometimes many so I think an Array is not the way to go. list.Add(strNode) is where I would be updating the comboBox.

Comment: If I try return list; it doesn't like it because the methid is declared as a string not a collection

Comment: I was thinking if I could properly refernce the cbxDomain then I could perhaps do something like ' Setting.cbxDomain.Add.Items(xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:domains/DAV:domain", nsmgr)) ' and perform it in a single call but currently haven;t been able to reference the cbxDomain comboBox from in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could populate your combobox from another form.
I will use example since I do not know you code structure but you will get the point.

```
public class User //Custom generic class
{
    public int _Id { get; set; }
    public string _Name { get; set; }
}

public class Functions
{
    public static List<User> PopulateComboboxWithUsers()
    {
        List<User> list = new List<User>();
        foreach(var something in somethingBig) //You can change this if you re reading form XML with it's variables or something else
        {
            list.Add(new User { _Id = something.Id, _Name = something.Name };
        }
        return list;
    }
}

public class Settings
{
    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        comboBox1.DataSource = Functions.PopulateComboboxWithUser();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "_Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "_Id";
    }
}
```

Other approach is to do the same function expect you will pass `comboBox` to it and you will do assigning inside it but I think this is more flexible.

Comment: If you want, give me your XML structure with example of what values you want to give to comboBox and then I will break it down for you

Comment: Thanks for that. I will give it a go. I am not using int_Id as I simply need the string. So the only change I need is to the creation of the function. Can I still pass in a value in 'List,User> PopulateComboBoxwithUsers(string someVariable)' if so then usimg the DataSource to reference the function might work for me. I was just looking at that within VS. but it is only showing Functions as an object not PopulatComnoWithUsers method. I assume that will chow in Intellesense.when writing the connnection.

Comment: of course you can pass values to function. If you need more help put here and I will edit my answer